# Netbeans Ruby Syntax Highlighting for Ruby 1.9?

Tags: ruby, netbeans

I've been getting some minor but annoying error warnings in Netbeans using the Ruby 1.9 colon hash syntax.  Example

```
%meta{charset: "UTF-8"}
```

This and all subsequent lines would be underlined.

Is there a simple way to update the Netbeans Ruby syntax highlighting?  I know that newer Netbeans versions no longer support Ruby, but Netbeans 6.9 still does it just fine--it just has minor annoyances like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like Haml, not Ruby. You should look at [Faq Ruby HAML Support](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqRubyHAMLSupport) on the Netbeans wiki.

Comment: That's probably right--I've long since moved on from Netbeans, so I'll accept your answer.